# DocuSign, cURL, json - from bash - error: ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE

Tags: json, bash, curl, docusignapi

my cURL is a bit rusty, but i'm trying to do a simple test and re-create the 'basic scenarios' - 'creating an envelope from a document' from the V2 REST api document, with a simple one page .docx file.

here is my curl command:

```
curl -X POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxx/envelopes \
-H "X-DocuSign-Authentication: \
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>me/Username><Password>pp</Password><IntegratorKey>...</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA" \
-d '--AAA \
Content-Type: application/json \
Content-Disposition: form-data \
\
{ \
"status":"sent", \
"emailBlurb":"Test Email Body", \
"emailSubject": "Test Email Subject EnvelopeDefFull", \
"documents": [{ \
        "name": "test1.docx", \
        "documentId":"1", \
        "order":"1" \
}], \
"recipients": { \
"signers" : [{ \
        "email": "me@myemail.com", \
        "name": "my name", \
        "recipientId":"1" \
}] \
} \
--AAA \
Content-Type: application/docx \
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.docx"; documentid=1 \
 \
@test1.docx \
 \
--AAA--'
```

and the error i get is:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE",
  "message": "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Envelope definition missing."
}
```

which is suspect is not actually the issue.

i think i have a cURL issue

possible issues: 
(1) backslashes inside -d single quotes 
(2) docx type and inclusion via @

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your spacing (and you're missing a `}` on your json portion).

If you take the same request and throw it in postman, remove all trailing spaces. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to get your cURL request working either, but here is a link that demonstrates another way of sending the payload: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/request_a_signature.html

One thing to point out (not affecting the current error though) is to make sure and include the `fileExtension` in your document, otherwise it is assumed to be a pdf:

```
"documents": [{ 
    "name": "test1.docx", 
    "documentId":"1", 
    "order":"1",
    "fileExtension" : "docx"
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it turned out i had multiple things wrong, and both Andrew and Nick were correct.  for the sake of completeness, here is my final working solution.

first, the bash script:

```
curl -X POST --upload-file send.txt \
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxx/envelopes \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA" \
-H "X-DocuSign-Authentication: \
<DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>...</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>..</Username><Password>...</Password><IntegratorKey>...</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>"
```

now, the contents of send.txt.

note the following:  i had to convert the doc to PDF and then insert the PDF bytes inline to the document, then close it.  i had this done when i saw nick's solution.  including it via @ did not work, i had to use 'cat' to append it to the actual send.txt file

```
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Distribution: form-data

{
"status":"sent",
"emailBlurb":"...",
"emailSubject":"Renew...",
"compositeTemplates":[{
        "serverTemplates": [{
                "sequence":1,
                "templateId":"xxxx",
                "templateRoles":[
                ]
        }],
        "inlineTemplates":[{
                "sequence":2,
                "recipients": {
                        "signers" :
                                [{
                                "email": "s...@yahoo.com",
                                "name": "...",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "accessCode": "xxxx",
                                "roleName": "..."
                                },]
                        },
        }],
"document": {
        "name": "Renew.pdf",
        "documentId":"1",
},
}],"notification": {
        "UseAccountDefaults":"false",
        "reminders": {
                "reminderEnabled": "true",
                "reminderDelay": "3",
                "reminderFrequency": "10"
        },
        "expirations": {
                "expireEnabled": "true",
                "expireAfter": "7",
                "expireWarn": "1"
        },
},
}

--AAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Renew.pdf"; documentid=1

%PDF-1.4^M%âãÏÓ^M1 0 obj
<<
...pdf bytes here...
/Info 29 0 R
>>
startxref
84324
%%EOF

--AAA--
```

i had to make templates specific to this application, simpler, less likely to expand or contract, so that the signature tags could be placed with absolute coordinates on the document rather than anchored.  the normal templates used interactively did not work.

lastly, the HTML headers have to be EXACTLY correct in terms of new line characters, one extra or missing and it fails.

thanks again for the help

matt